# Email configuration

Tags: c#, smtp, gmail

Hi guys I am doing email function for the first time and I searched up on how to do a email

```
try
{
    MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();

    message.From = new MailAddress("from@gmail.com");
    message.To.Add(new MailAddress("to@gmail.com"));
    message.Subject = "Test";
    message.Body = "Content";

    smtp.Port = 587;
    smtp.Host = "gmail.com";
    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("from@gmail.com", "password");
    smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    smtp.Send(message);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("err: " + ex.Message);
}
```

I tried running this but I am not sure what is the problem... i did not use IIS or anything

(update)
I uploaded the error image in this website
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WR4E7.jpg

Comment: what is the exception you get?

Comment: Are you get some exceptions from this code? Or email just undelivered? What is your problem here?

Comment: Which error give it is.?

Comment: I have  e code do you needed.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This one will Help you..! try this..!**

```
try
{
                MailMessage Msg = new MailMessage();
                // Sender e-mail address.

                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                //smtp object.        

                Msg.From = new MailAddress("from@gmail.com");
                // Recipient e-mail address.

                Msg.To.Add(to@gmail.com);
                //here you can pass textbox value how need to send mail.

                Msg.Subject = "Please confirm your subscription";
                Msg.Body = "<body></body>";


                Msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
                // your remote SMTP server IP.

                smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                smtp.Port = 587;
                smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("from@gmail.com", "password");
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                smtp.Send(Msg);
                //Msg = null;
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Message.Show("Error:" + ex.Message);
}
```